# Creating Media Items using the RESTful ItemService API

Tags: media-library, sitecore-services-client, sitecore-api

Quick background, re-building a "product importer" exe that was written for v7 using the old web API and ideally want to replicate all the old logic to work in the new v8 site using the RESTful ItemService API.

Part of the logic, involved "creating media items" , i.e. programatically downloading images from a source url and uploading them to the sitecore media library and saving the media items on an image field property on the product item page.

In the old API this was done using using the Create Media items logic ,see page 10 of the old web API documentation here https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf

I cant find a way to do the equivalent in the new API, and if someone knows how or can suggest the best alternative to archive the same result, that would be greatly appreciated, please also add some sample code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have seen this, https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/creating-media-items-creates-duplicate-folder-names but because i am working outside the sitecore context (without the sitecore context) this wont work but something similar to this would be great.

Comment: Could you please post the entire API request body to be passed for this to work via web api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a solution to this, if anyone was wondering how to get around it, apparently the old Web API still works in V8.2.4 so basically i implemented the media creating logic available in the old Web API, see link in question for the documentations.

I was under the impression that the old Web API doesn't work anymore in V8+ but got confirmation from Sitecore that this is not the case and there are no plans to deprecate the Old Web API.

So in a nutshell now got a hybrid application with new and old API logic.