# How do we create a media item through the web API?

Tags: item-web-api

I am trying to use the create call but not sure how to send the media payload to it. Tried base64 to the "Media" field and that did not work.

Comment: Does this question contain what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112991/sitecore-item-web-api-uploading-media-item-with-template

Comment: Yes... it is using v1 that is not supported in later versions.. trying to do this with the itemservice REST api

Comment: Are you sure it's not supported anymore? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7655/creating-media-items-using-the-restful-itemservice-api

Comment: Yeah... seems like it got taken out in 9.0. The APIs throw a 404